# xml parse start tag expected R

Tags: xml, r, parsing, tags

I do not know a lot about xml but I need to read this file so that R can 
use it. However, there is always an error "document empty, start tag expected, '<' not found". But I cannot see the origin of the error.
Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MappingTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/ ./Alevin.xsd" xmlns="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/" name="AdvSubgraphTestGenerator2">
  <TestGenerator className="tests.generatorTests.AdvSubgraphTestRunner"/>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="7.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1612.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.6851389854194017"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.9861088559313271"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="0.7559889069056674"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="0.6648338346749284"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.279045304613785"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="0.4505067333055669"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="8.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="846.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.741814530894711"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="1.0019396461682453"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="0.868390100905683"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.854673959898261"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="1.295691487310222"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="0.6805885859898158"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="9.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="609.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.212517958069722"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.08677137867839191"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="1.9927278019276755"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.6370875136672722"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="1.8573960873462065"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="1.7266332660325572"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="578.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.145412191385898"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.826946783775961"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="1.8202071941911595"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.5890364574294114"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.2117994159315804"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="1.1993780131111107"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="11.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="797.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.3954850079335364"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.019578501527560466"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.0860109027715414"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.854555495387745"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.584217996538307"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="2.1648172533072234"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="12.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="892.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.4913004237744385"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.7696498939789347"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="2.201723978314626"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.04191205905592"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.376993537716656"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.034262661127799"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="13.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="872.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.047126232292386"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.9952229587725951"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.3794406500249257"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.6523543005400327"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.048441149178422"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.133358034963522"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="14.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="891.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.987660356945407"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.2484076205543828"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.9080988222890496"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.1670218484160566"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.2472187629267433"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.1328785000072386"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="15.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1162.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.2234619923069414"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.45771183680269933"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="2.9215253413041196"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.054840069986192"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.442550183039827"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.995284651861695"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="16.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1113.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.0926238844236447"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.7808319615152142"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.0087947748201787"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.1883371528470357"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.663210710605434"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="2.7728208750298773"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="17.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="2454.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.23606797749979"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="4.143188604518091"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="4.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="3.2916550003635034"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="4.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.7605883080698828"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="5.220399731228472"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="18.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="2516.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.9840593925343335"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.3636812390986559"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="4.238514242266579"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.2503830421805113"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="4.0227880048448625"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="6.649563197244915"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
</MappingTest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code into RStudio, enclosed it in single quotes and assigned it to an object, "doc"

```
doc <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <MappingTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/ ./Alevin.xsd" xmlns="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/" name="AdvSubgraphTestGenerator2">
  <TestGenerator className="tests.generatorTests.AdvSubgraphTestRunner"/>
  <ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
```

remainder omitted here

Then the following seemed fine:

```
test <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)
```

Do you want to retrieve some element(s) of doc using something like

```
xpathSApply(doc, "xpath expression", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. In fact, I want to retrieve some elements of doc, but what is xpath exression. Can you give me an example like return all results of VertexConnectivity? Why did you not use xmlParse()?

Comment: Add the URL of the site you are searching to your question, or in a comment, and I will send you the XPath expression.  I need to use Firebug to look at the actual HTML code of that URL.  As to xmlParse, I actually don't know whether it makes a difference.  I have been using htmlTreeParse for a while and never explored alternatives.

Comment: That would be very kind of you. But in fact, there is no URL because my java programme generates the xml file. So, I just need to known how to turn the results of each metric into a vector or other thing so that I can plot the results as a function.

Comment: Sorry, I have spent too much time on this.  I ran this xpathSApply(test, "//ScenarioMetric[@name = 'VertexConnectivity0']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) but it returns a list, because the result value is in another attribute.  I tried converting the xml to a character string and using regex to clean it up and put into a dataframe but I got bogged down.  Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I posted another question which solves the problem if you are interested to see it.

Comment: Good for you, Fab Ian.  I will look for it.  And thanks for accepting a crippled answer, but effort  :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard XML Parser will check for `<` as the first character. There is a chance like the XML are created in a non standard way potentially have hidden character as the first one. You will not be able to see it opening in an Editor.

In such scenarios, try to read the first character of the file using a standard file reading API and try printing the character to int

```
#Scala
import scala.io.Source
val file = Source.fromFile("filename.xml")
file.hasNext match {
 case true => println(s"Character int :${file.next.toInt}")
 case false => println(s"Empty File")
}

> Character int :65279
```

Which is actually a zero-width no-break space.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm